# Why does an each closure over an empty collection run at least once?

Tags: groovy

I have a function that downloads files from a web server that is sometimes fed an empty collection. In the function I call each on that collection and what I would expect to happen is that the function just exits with the each closure not being run at all. The problem is that it does get run with an empty `filename` parameter and the creation of the FileOutputStream goes boom when it is fed a directory instead of a file.

```
def get(String baseUrl, List files, String targetDir) {
    files.each { filename ->
    // Goes BOOM on next line
    def fos = new FileOutputStream(targetDir + File.separator + filename)
    ...
}
```

Why does Groovy behave like this and what should I do instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't, so I assume `files` contains something (like `null`?)

```
[].each {
  println "boom"  // This doesn't appear
}

[null].each {
  println "pow!"  // this does
}
```

Assuming it is `null`s in your files List that is causing the issue, you can get rid of them by:

```
files.findAll().each { filename ->
  def fos = new FileOutputStream( new File( targetDir, filename ) )
  ...
```

Or of course, make the thing that generates the List not add nulls in the first place

#### Edit

Actually, it sounds like you have a List with empty strings in it...

The `findAll` fix should still work, as empty strings evaluate to `false` under Groovy Truth

#### Edit 2

As a quick note, you can probably change:

```
def fos = new FileOutputStream( new File( targetDir, filename ) )
...
```

to:

```
new File( targetDir, filename ).withOutputStream { fos ->
  ...
```

And it will [ensure the stream is closed](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#withOutputStream%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) for you :-)

Comment: Awesome answer (as usual), I'll try it when I get back to work tomorrow!